# Get aura:id and selected option value in controller for <lightning:select>

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, javascript-controller, table

I have a dropdown in a table in a lightning component. Here is the code of that td.

```
<tbody>
<aura:iteration items="{!v.recipientList}" var="recipient">
    <tr class="slds-hint-parent" 
        id="{!recipient.rowCount}">
        <td>
            <lightning:select aura:id="{!'recCo-'+recipient.rowCount}" onchange="{!c.changedRecipContact}">
                <option selected="selected" value="None">-None-</option>
                <aura:iteration items="{!v.consList}" var="cons">
                    <option value="{!cons.id}" selected="{!(recipient.contact.Id == cons.id)}">{!cons.name}</option>
                </aura:iteration>
            </lightning:select>
        </td>
        .
        ..
        <!--Other td inputs-->
    </tr>
</aura:iteration></tbody>
```

Once a contact is selected, I am trying to get the aura:id using lines below

> var a = event.getSource();
> var selectId = a.getLocalId();

But I am getting ***{!'recCo-'+recipient.rowCount}***, not the dynamic value.
Please advice how to get the ID and < option > value  in the controller. If there is any other way of getting this id like using datasets or something like that and then the option value from it, please let me know.

I have been using < select > since a lot of years but it is broken in Chrome browser so I am trying to get this done by lightning:select. [Here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/309091/dropdown-selected-values-not-displaying-in-lightning-component-in-chrome-browser) is the link to that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aura:id` does not support merge fields. It is always a literal value. Use another field instead, such as `name`.

Comment: @sfdxfox I am a big fan of you. I used name field and used `event.getSource().get("v.name")` to get the desired value. I am selecting this as Answered but Unfortunately, lightning:select also showing -none- after selecting the dropdown in Chrome browser. [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/309091/dropdown-selected-values-not-displaying-in-lightning-component-in-chrome-browser) is the link. Could you please help me with this.